# Writing to flash drive becomes very slow after 10% completion

Tags: memory, usb-flash-drive, blocking

I have a new 32GB Kingston flash drive. When writing files the transfer speed reduces to 1-3MBps after copying approx 10% of data, while the initial transfer speed was 50MBps+. Sometimes it retains the high speed if I pause the writing and resume.

When observing with flash tool 'HD_Speed', I can see that during the write the 'block size' changes very frequently and whenever it happens the speed goes down.

Any ideas? Is this because of a problem with the drive?

I had noticed it when the drive was new, now I have partitioned it but the problem still exists.

I have tried formatting the partitions with different combinations of Fat32/NTFS and different block sizes from 512 bytes to 4196 bytes.

Comment: only because im curious, where do you bougth your Flash Drive, i mean in an established store or from internet(ebay.... as example, china web stores)

Comment: I bought it from SnapDeals, an established ecom site